# Is it possible to publish a video stored in Google+ directly to YouTube?

Tags: youtube, google-plus

I have a video in my Google+ account, which I would like to publish directly to YouTube, without the need to download and re-upload it first.  Is this possible?

My YouTube and Google+ accounts are linked, but so far I only see how to share things the other direction (sharing a YouTube video on my Google+ page, for instance).

Answer (score 1):

You can now directly import Google+ videos into YouTube on the upload page.

[image: https://plus.google.com/+AengelnEnglund/posts/VoGMVCYKPkh]